# Filter In Webservices Response

Tags: android

I am getting the response from the server but value is containing html tags .I want to remove those tag while storing the value in variable. which approach should  i follow. Thanks for considering.Here i am pasting some piece of response:

```
 "<p><strong>The item is a 17.78 cm (7) tablet that is packed with multiple features. What is most inviting is that it enables you to voice call your friends or have a video chat with them on its  0.3M front mounted camera. Music lovers will also enjoy it: from its carefully positioned speakers to its DolbyÂ® audio enhancement, the A1000 delivers a dazzling music</strong></p>\n<p><strong>Enjoy Voice Calling</strong></p>\n<p>The  comes with SIM support for Voice Calling. Use it like a tablet or a regular phone. The choice is all yours.</p>\n<p><strong>Enhanced Stereo Speakers</strong></p>\n<p>Enjoy an enhanced audio experience for.. "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i got my solution. its working fine for me.

```
String properResponse= responseWithHtml.replaceAll("\\<.*?>","");
```